# How do I get the whole array that is logged in console to appear in the selected id tag?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The console displays the entire array, of names of representatives per state, but when I put it into the html tag, it just displays the last name in the array. How do I get the whole array to appear in 'results'?

```
function showData (data) {
    let reps = data.results;

    for (let i = 0; i < reps.length; i++) {
        console.log(reps[i].name, reps[i].party)

        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
        `<div>${reps[i].name} (${reps[i].party})</div>`;
    }
}
```

Console log =

Dianne Feinstein D
Kamala Harris D

Browser =

Kamala Harris (D)

I only get "Kamala Harris (D)" when I display it on the html 'results' id, but not "Dianne Feinstein (D)"

Comment: In loop you should append previous value of document.getElementById('results').innerHTML . For example, Tag = Tag+'value' . Also set value as blank for first time.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the innerHTML with each iteration. You want to keep adding the results of each iteration to a variable and then set the innerHTML to the value of that variable after the loop completes.

```
function showData (data) {
    let reps = data.results;
    let inner = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < reps.length; i++) {
        console.log(reps[i].name, reps[i].party)
        inner += `<div>${reps[i].name} (${reps[i].party})</div>`
    }
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = inner;
}
```